# Most efficient way to manipulate ISN numbers in TCP headers

Tags: c, tcp, header, network-programming, low-level

I am currently trying to write a program that will be able to create stable a TCP connection and have complete control over the ISN numbers. I've been writing in C and I am at a point where my very limited knowledge has reached its limits and I was wondering if there's a better way of doing it.

What I tried was building the headers manually, using raw sockets to send and recieve the packets without the kernel interfering, which is a challenge.

So regardless of language, what do you reckon is the most efficient and easiest way of manipulating the ISN?

Comment: What operating system are we talking about? Why do you need this level of control to begin with? In short: what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Well I'm using Backtrack5, and as for the reason, I read this article on covert channels in tcp connections and wanted to try the channel proposed. Purely on a hobby basis of course, to see if it could be done (meaning if I could do it) :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, ISN is generatred in a random way to prevent ISN perediction attack (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/01/tcp-sequence-number-attacks/).

The Linux Network stack, use the function `tcp_v4_init_sequence` to generate the ISN (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L101), this function call `secure_tcp_sequence_number` function (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/secure_seq.c#L106) to do the job. Take a look at this function and try to clone it so can use it with your code from userspace.

If you have enough time you can look at **section 3** of the `RFC 6528` (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6528.txt), it describe an algorithm on how to generate ISN:

```
ISN = M + F(localip, localport, remoteip, remoteport, secretkey)
```

And try to implement it, if you want :)

Comment: Thank you, that's some very useful references.

Comment: links are broken

Comment: links broken, as Apr 2021, can check https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/core/secure_seq.c