# Initial Sequence Number generation in Linux TCP stack

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

What is the procedure for generating the Initial Sequence Numbers (ISN)
in LINUX tcp/ip protocol. I know the procedure for ISN generation in
the LINUX kernels 2.4 to 2.6 that are described in pages 7 & 8 of
[Embedding Covert Channels into TCP/IP](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fteam.gray-world.net%2Fpapers%2Fih05coverttcp.pdf&ei=WnxCUPzSNYbP0QWy9YDQDw&usg=AFQjCNFL-Vgx4GP10anGYGsrJDo9vwssRg&sig2=wJd0SxLHGm2ORptWusTs0A). I have searched for similar
procedures in later kernels, but to my dismay I couldn't find any. I understand that much details may not be available for obvious reasons related to security. As I'm verifying the possibilities of implementing a similar steganography scheme(as described in the link) in the later Linux kernels, I am badly in need of some information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read my answer here:
[Most efficient way to manipulate ISN numbers in TCP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223002/most-efficient-way-to-manipulate-isn-numbers-in-tcp-headers/12223914#12223914)

This algorithm is used on the latest kernel TCP Stack (`3.5`).

**EDIT** : See image below to see all concerned kernels versions[image]

**EDIT2** : See the sources of the kernel for older versions of the function `secure_tcp_sequence_number`:

[Kernel 2.4.22](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=linux-2.4.22#L2139)

[Kernel 2.6.30](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=2.6.30#L1562)

[Kernel 2.6.39](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=2.6.39#L1528)

[Kernel 3.0](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=3.0#L1528)

[Kernel 3.1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/secure_seq.c?v=3.1#L104) : (MD5 has replaced half-MD4)

Comment: Thank You.
Could you tell me which is the latest kernel in which the ISN generation method described in RFC1948 is implemented?

Comment: @sjsam : Please take a look at the image to see the versions.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out.
Did you mean the old algorithm(RFC1948) is used in Kernels until 3.4?
(I can see 3.5 is written brighter than all the other versions)
Or is it till 2.6.33(as pointed by the arrow) the older one is used?

Once again thanks for the help..

Comment: @sjsam : I think that the new algorithm (RFC 6528 - February 2012) is used from kernel 3.1. Before that i think that the other algorithm(RFC1948) was used.

Comment: In the formula it is given that M is a four microsecond timer. What exactly is it? I guess, the M is four bytes initialised to zero at the beginning. For the first ISN the modified second word of the MD5 hash is exactly the ISN. From the second ISN the the timer which should be incremented by 1 bit on every 4 microseconds should be added. Is it a plausible explanation?

Comment: This is really not an answer without some relevant text cited from the citations.

Answer (score 2):

After more careful reading of [RFC6528](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6528.txt) and [RFC1948](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1948.txt) I came to a conclusion that the algorithm for generating Initial Sequence Numbers(ISNs) as specified in RFC1948 :

```
       ISN = M + F(LocalIP, LocalPort, RemoteIP, RemotePort, Secretkey)
```

has not changed. Instead, the algorithm which was proposed by Bellovin S.M in RFC1948 is formally specified and taken into the Standards Track(as per [RFC2119](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)) in RFC6528 which was written together by Bellovin S.M and Gont. F.. As the now obsolete RFC1948 can't be used in any documentations, RFC6528 has replaced it.

But as pointed out in the answer to my original question MD5 has replaced half-MD4 as the Hash Function from kernels 3.1. This is completely justified by RFC6528 as it did give the flexibility to change F() which is the Pseudo-Random function.
(Please have a look at the links for more details).

Answer (score 2):

Update to previous answers so that to represent current state (2019 and Linux kernel 5.1.3) because algorithm to generate `ISN`s in the kernel was changed again to be more secure.

[secure_tcp_seq](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.3/source/net/core/secure_seq.c#L132) now uses `SipHash` (add–rotate–xor) functions to generate ISN based on initial secret key, source and destination IP address and port. I suppose this change was related to hash collision vulnerability resulted in [hash flooding](https://www.securityweek.com/hash-table-collision-attacks-could-trigger-ddos-massive-scale) attacks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this relates to hash flooding? Users don't get to influence sequence number.